# How and where to add an sbteclipse task?

Tags: eclipse, scala, lift, sbt

I'm following the instructions here: http://blog.colinajohnston.com/scala-ide-200rc2-sbt-0112-lift-24-m5-now-with to setup eclipse with lift and sbt but I'm stuck here:

```
sbteclipse task:

$sbt
>eclipse with-sources
```

Not sure how to proceed at this point. I take it that I need the sbteclipse plugin (which I'm about to install) but how do I actually add the task and also is that going to also load the dependencies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to install the sbteclipse as explained here: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Installing-sbteclipse

You can install it either globally or at the project level.  I would recommend installing it globally since A) it won't clutter your project settings and B) you won't have to install it for every project individually.

Once the plugin is installed, you'll be able to simply run the "eclipse" command and it will pull in all the necessary dependencies automatically.

Comment: All setup and working great. Thanks a lot. I'm guessing there's no way to launch the project from the EclipseIDE instead of using $sbt ~container-start which would listen for source changes?